# Which is the lightest weight: Canvas or Grid?

Tags: wpf, performance, wpf-controls

Sometimes I need to group a couple items together and I don't need much in terms of layouting from the parent Panel. Pretty much any panel would do.

In those cases, is there a clear winner between the different Panel types, or are they effectively equivalent?

Comment: I know this one: A tonne of Canvas and a tonne of Grid both weight the same! it's a trick question!!! ;-)

Comment: Note: I am asking because I use these panels as the root of some customcontrols that might be repeated dozens or hundreds of times in my app.

Comment: How interior controls will handle layout? If you'll have to handle it properly with a Canvas...

Comment: possible duplicate of [In what order are Panels the most efficient in terms of render time and performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946811/in-what-order-are-panels-the-most-efficient-in-terms-of-render-time-and-performa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Canvas is much lighter than Grid when processing layout.

But you say:

> I don't need much in terms of layout.

Canvas may not even provide you with the little you need. Though it might not be much effort to make a Canvas work for you. It depends on what you're doing, of course.

Comment: Just need to overlay two-three items quite often, both taking up the entire width/height of the parent panel. Canvas it is then...

Answer (score 1):

Canvas is lightweight for its layout (Measure and Arrange) pass is much basic and simpler than Grid's.

Having said that, Grid would give you a lot of flexibility in terms of adapting to its  container and thus to the screen (including screen dimensions, resolution and dpi) than a canvas.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to bear in mind is that a Grid will autosize itself to fit its contents, whereas a Canvas will not.   This matters when the Canvas or Grid is nested itself inside some other panel.   Especially if the size of the panel can change (e.g. displaying a variable sized list), a Grid or StackPanel can be easier to use.