# Grid and StackPanel, which has the better performance?

Tags: wpf, windows, windows-phone-8

Let's read these codes, I've defined two similar UserControls in a Windows Phone 8 project and I really want to which of them is better. I've check the profiling, it seems they are almost the same.

UserControl 1, using grid's property to design my layout.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}" Height="108">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Rectangle Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Height="108" Width="54" Fill="Blue"></Rectangle>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Caption" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="URLURLURLURLURLURL" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

UserControl 2, using StackPanel to design my layout.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}" Height="108">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Rectangle Height="108" Width="54" Fill="Red"></Rectangle>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="Caption" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="URLURLURLURLURLURL" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

It looks like the basic layout is the same. But when I use XAML Spy to analyse the Visualizing tree, UserControl 1 has less nodes, but it costs a little more memory. Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In what order are Panels the most efficient in terms of render time and performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946811/in-what-order-are-panels-the-most-efficient-in-terms-of-render-time-and-performa)

Comment: This is blatantly a duplicate, the accepted answer even just links to and cites the answer to the other question.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You may be interested in the answers to this question: [In what order are Panels the most efficient in terms of render time and performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9946811/302677)

The short answer is it depends on how many children the panels have, and how those elements are sized and positioned. But in most cases, a `StackPanel` will be more efficient than a `Grid` as it has both a faster measure and arrangement pass.

To quote from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9996707/302677):

> **Grid**
>
> > Defines a flexible grid area that consists of columns and rows.
>
> This can be the most performance intensive panel if proportional
>   sizing or auto sizing is used. Calculating child item size can be a
>   complex combination of the native size of the item and the layout
>   specified by the grid. Layout is also the most complicated of all the
>   panels. Slow to medium performance for the measure pass and slow to
>   medium performance for the arrangement pass.
>
> **StackPanel**
>
> > Arranges child elements into a single line that can be oriented horizontally or vertically.
>
> The StackPanel measures its children using either native or relative
>   sizing in the opposite direction from its orientation and native
>   sizing in the direction of its orientation (alignment does nothing in
>   this direction). This makes it a mid-level performer in this area. The
>   Arrangement pass is simply, just laying out the items in order.
>   Probably the second-best performance for this pass. Medium performance
>   for the measure pass and fast performance for the layout pass.

Also in regards to memory consumption, both objects are different and take up different amounts of memory, and a `Grid` has `RowDefinitions` and `ColumnDefinitions`, so it actually contains more objects than your `StackPanel`