# How to vertically aligned a TextBlock in a StackPanel

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am doing this in c# on Windows phone. I want a TextBlock vertically center aligned in a StackPanel with height of 58. Here is what I did:

```
<StackPanel Height="58" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" Foreground="black"  />
            </StackPanel>
```

But it does not vertically center aligned. Can you please tell me why and how can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Check this post. StackPanel is probably a wrong option in your case.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918847/how-can-i-vertically-align-a-textbox-inside-a-stackpanel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should go with the `Grid` than `StackPanel` as @The-First-Tiger & @Krishna mentioned above and also have you misplaced the `VerticalAlignment`? You wanted the `TextBlock` to align vertically center, so it should be like this:

```
 <Grid Height="58" >
   <TextBlock  VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}"  Foreground="black"  />
 </Grid
```

Comment: Thanks. I am new to C# Windows programming. Is Grid more heavy than StackPanel? meaning does it use more memory? In general, should I use StackPanel instead of grid if I can?

Comment: @michael As I'm not clear with the memory consumption of each of them would suggest to have a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575854/grid-and-stackpanel-which-has-the-better-performance

Answer (score 0):

`StackPanel` is not for this. It 'stacks' things not aligns them.

Try using a `Grid` instead:

```
<Grid Height="58">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Height="20" Foreground="black"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN docs about StackPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> A StackPanel Arranges child elements into a single line that can be oriented
>   horizontally or vertically.

So in your case, StackPanel is not the right control to use. If you want your control to be fixed at a particular position, you can use [DockPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) and place your control inside it. Children Controls of DockPanel can use the `.Dock` property to align themselves

```
<DockPanel>
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Name="btn"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></Button>
</DockPanel>
```