# Stick to the bottom of a StackPanel

Tags: wpf

In my window, there is a Grid that takes up 100% of the available vertical space. Inside that Grid is a StackPanel with another StackPanel and a Frame inside. I would like to have that Frame stick to the bottom of the parent StackPanel.

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel>
       //normal content
     </StackPanel>
     <Frame /> // should stick to the bottom
</StackPanel>
```

So that, for example, when the user resizes the Window and the Grid gains height, the Frame inside sticks to the bottom.

I have tried various things, using `VerticalAlign="Stretch"` or a DockPanel and assigning the Frame a `DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"`, but to no success. I'd be thankful for a hint or two. I don't need the StackPanel to be a StackPanel, it can also be a DockPanel.

Comment: Please post your grid code and let know what height does other rows in the grid should be at...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

A `StackPanel` is not the correct `Panel` to use for your requirements as they do not provide the same layout and resizing capabilities as a `Grid`. Therefore, simply replace it with a `Grid`, give the majority of the space to the inner `StackPanel` and then the `Frame` will stick to the bottom.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />   
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
       //normal content
     </StackPanel>
     <Frame Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

You can find out more about the different WPF `Panel`s in the [Panels Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: @peter: If possible mark this answer as solution :)

Answer (score 15):

Looks more like a use case for `DockPanel`

```
<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel>
        <!--//normal content-->
    </StackPanel>
    <Frame DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/> <!--// should stick to the bottom-->
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: A `DockPanel` is *not* the appropriate `Panel` to use in this situation as they are heavyweight controls and the functionality that they provide is not required here. A simple `Grid` would be far more efficient.

Comment: Difficult to say if DockPanel is not appropriate, without knowing the use case. I will let @Peter decide.

Comment: @Sheridan A DockPanel actually provides less functionality than a Grid and has better performance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9996707/1988326

Comment: That list is NOT an ordered list and does not take into consideration a layout as simple as the one that we are discussing here. The time-consuming parts of a `Grid` control come from complex `ColumnDefinition` and `RowDefinition` setups, along with its star sizing capabilities. As always, it depends on how it will be used.

Answer (score -1):

According to [MSDN docs about StackPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> A StackPanel Arranges child elements into a single line that can be oriented
>   horizontally or vertically.

So in your case, StackPanel is not the right control to use. If you want your control to be fixed at a particular position, you can use [DockPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) and place your control inside it.

```
<DockPanel>
        <Frame DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
</DockPanel>
```