# WPF How to make a Viewbox aware of its available space from within a StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a custom WPF control based on Soroosh Davaee’s ImageButton example at http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/773386/WPF-ImageButton. The custom control combines an Image and TextBlock in a horizontal StackPanel within a Button. (BTW, to get Soroosh’s example to run, I had to edit the solution properties so that “SampleView” is the startup project rather than “ExtendedButton” being the startup project.)

I want the text in the TextBlock to automatically shrink if necessary to avoid clipping at the right edge if the text is too long to fit naturally in the button. For example, if I edit Soroosh's MainWindow.xaml to make the button text too long to fit...

```
    ...
    <EB:ImageButton Width="100" Height="30" Content="TextTooLongToFitInTheButton" Grid.Row="2"
    ...
    <EB:ImageButton Width="100" Height="30" Content="TextTooLongToFitInTheButton" Grid.Row="2"
    ...
```

...the result is the following buttons with clipped text:

[image: Buttons with clipped text]

In researching this, it seems the simplest way to auto-shrink the content of a TextBlock is to wrap it within a Viewbox:

```
<Viewbox StretchDirection="DownOnly" Stretch="Fill">
    <TextBlock ... />
</Viewbox>
```

`DownOnly` apparently prevents the Viewbox from *enlarging* the text to fill the space, and `Fill` (as opposed to `Uniform`) seems to tell it to stretch (shrink) *only* the dimension that needs to shrink (i.e. the horizontal dimension in my case).

In Soroosh's example Generic.xaml file, I wrapped the TextBlock in such a Viewbox:

```
     <Button >
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
             <Image Margin="2 0"
                    Source="{TemplateBinding Image}"
                    Width="{TemplateBinding ImageWidth}"
                    Height="{TemplateBinding ImageHeight}"
                    Visibility="{TemplateBinding Image,Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConvertor}}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
I added-->   <Viewbox StretchDirection="DownOnly" Stretch="Fill">
             <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
I added-->   </Viewbox>
         </StackPanel>
     </Button>
```

This produced exactly the same clipped button text. Just experimenting, I tried forcing the Viewbox to have a fixed width...

```
             <Viewbox StretchDirection="DownOnly" Stretch="Fill" Width="60">
```

...which produced this:

[image: Viewbox with manually-sized width]

...which shows the capability of the Viewbox, if only it could somehow know its available width when it's inside the StackPanel.

I did note that if I wrap the Viewbox around the whole StackPanel, it successfully auto-shrinks the entire content of the StackPanel:

```
     <Button >
         <Viewbox StretchDirection="DownOnly" Stretch="Fill" Width="60">
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                 <Image Margin="2 0"
                    Source="{TemplateBinding Image}"
                    Width="{TemplateBinding ImageWidth}"
                    Height="{TemplateBinding ImageHeight}"
                    Visibility="{TemplateBinding Image,Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConvertor}}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                 <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
             </StackPanel>
         </Viewbox>
     </Button>
```

...which produces very nearly what I want:

[image: Viewbox wrapping the entire StackPanel]

...but both the image and text are shrunk, and I want *only the text shrunk*.

How can I make the Viewbox, wrapping only the TextBox, know its available width (and height, I suppose) from within a cell of the StackPanel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem. The solution is simply to *not* use a `StackPanel` to do any kind of layout that requires re-sizing of child controls. It's simply not the correct `Panel` for the job. Instead, try using a `Grid` panel, which *will* resize its child controls. The `StackPanel` control is really only good for the most basic of layout duties... try anything more adventurous and you'll find yourself getting these issues.

One other alternative is to use the [`TextBlock.TextTrimming` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimming(v=vs.110).aspx) to trim the text instead... you could put the full text into a `ToolTip` too.

Comment: Agreed 100%. People tend to overuse `StackPanel`, but it has too many limitations, this being the main one: its potential available space is always infinite in the direction of its items flow, so it is unable to communicate its children how much available space they have in that direction.

Comment: Thank you for the eye-opener. I did not realize StackPanels have such limitations. I ended up using a `DockPanel` as it's simpler than `Grid`.

Comment: @phonetagger, you should be aware that the `DockPanel` is a fairly heavyweight `Panel` and should really only be used if you require that exact functionality. Compared with a `DockPanel`, a `Grid Panel` is far more lightweight and you can create the same display using it.

Comment: @Sheridan, by heavyweight, what do you mean? In what ways is it heavyweight?

Comment: Heavyweight as in code, RAM, etc., eg. lower performance. But ignore that comment... I got it back to front: [In what order are Panels the most efficient in terms of render time and performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946811/in-what-order-are-panels-the-most-efficient-in-terms-of-render-time-and-performa).

Comment: Hi, how would you go about using a ViewBox in a horizontal ListView (to achieve horizontal list view I used horizontal StackPanel within ListView's ItemsPanel)

Comment: @DanielGruszczyk, please ask a new question, if you haven't already.