# Open WPF window is slow due to layout affecting

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, xaml, layout

I have a problem with wpf. The problem is my window, which uses some `auto` and `*` columns in a `Grid`, it is opening very slow. I've used the Visual Studio debugger to investigate what the trouble is, and found it in the layout section. The message is:

> Changes were made to XAML visual tree that required the size and/or position of all affected elements to be computed.

Here is a screenshot of the debugger:

[image: Debug Information]

What is the best way to detect the exact problem with the layout? Or are there some general rules I could follow?

Thank you very much, I did not experience this behaviour with wpf before, even with large usercontrols / windows...

**EDIT**
I don't use any animation of transformation to rotate controls. In general it is a very flat window. As an additional information, scrolling through `GridView`s in the window is also very slow.

Comment: Do you use expensive `LayoutTransform` animations instead of `RenderTranform`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I only use WPF default behaviour and did not specify `LayoutTransform` or `RenderTranform.`

Comment: What exactly happens at the moment layout starts taking so much time? Do you use non-virtualized containers (and begin filling them)? Do you add thousands of controls to some `Grid`? See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9946811/1997232) question, it should be helpful.

Comment: Not thousends, maybe between 50 and 70. Not more. I will read the article, seems to be very informatic.

Comment: So you are adding ~60 controls when it happens. Adding where? How? It could be complicated templates or adding each item triggering layout pass for container (or even whole window). In either case consider to providing related xaml and code. Another thing I could think of is relative bindings of control margins, etc., whenever adding one control will cause a chain reaction.

Comment: The UI does not use `Trigger`. It is build from 8 `UserControl`s which are added programatically. The 8 `UserControl`s than contains the other controls. But no advanced styling, merging binding or some thing like that. Event replacing auto to some fixed value does not help.

Comment: Would have to see under the hood to diagnose this one. Could be any number of things that just a basic description won't help much to identify.

Comment: We can't diagnose the cause just by looking at the symptoms. Post some code to detail your implementation.

Comment: There's a trial-and-error approach. Loading a blank window to get the baseline and then slowly add you controls into the window one by one to see the difference. Setting a fix number to your height and width on your grid is also a nice thing to try on. Eventually, you'll be able to get your answer on what caused the problem

Comment: @BendEg I've experience problems if I hook up my * incorrectly, replace them with fixed sizes for the time being and see if that helps you isolate your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head (and re-iterating a few of the comments):

- Are you using nested `IsSharedSizeScope`? This can cause cascading layout updates.
- Have you turned off virtualization and have many items in the grid? This can cause slow and studdering performance.
- Try to isolate the issue by removing stuff until it works (or removing a lot and adding things back until the issue starts to reappear)
- Post your code here so we help you better

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The reason was accidentally switched OFF virtualization in ListView in XAML file. Probably copy/paste from web. Changing from false to true made the magic.

```
VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
```